# Laser and photographic paper

Tags: paper, laser

Let's assume I have some pieces of photographic paper (RC) in dark room. Is it possible in such environment to draw simple shapes on the paper with simple laser pointer?

If not, do you know any kind of cheap light sensitive material, that would allow to do something like that?

I am total newbie in photography and I need such knowledge to make simple presentation for studies.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible in such environment to draw simple shapes on the paper with simple laser pointer?

**Yes.** You might want to start with a green laser pointer, though -- red light is often used in darkrooms as a "safe" light because photographic paper is less sensitive to red light.

> If not, do you know any kind of cheap light sensitive material, that would allow to do something like that?

Two candidates are:

- **blueprint paper:** You can buy some or [make your own](http://chemistry.about.com/od/colorchemistryprojects/a/How-To-Make-Blueprint-Paper.htm).
- **Liquid Light:** This is a liquid photosensitive emulsion that you can apply to many different materials. [B&H is one source](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/45028-REG/Rockland_LLE8_Liquid_Light_Photo_Emulsion.html).

Comment: There are many people on the web using "UV photoresist" and appropriate lasers to layout circuits for etching - which should also be an inexpensive material to try.

Answer (score 1):

A laser is special light, but light no less.

It boils down to what frequencies of light the photographic paper is sensible to. The laser is (basically speaking) only one frequency. This frequency should be part of the spectrum of frequencies that the paper works with.

Then it's a matter of knowing the sensitivity. This determines how quickly you can move the laser over the paper and still create a result that's visible enough.

I'd just try it out and see how it works.